# Empty Subscriber Count for Spotify Playlists

Tags: api, spotify

I cannot seem to reliably fetch the subscriberCount for playlists using the Spotify Apps API. It will nearly always return zero, unless I manually view the playlist before making the API call.

Is there any way to programmatically 'browse' to a playlist, so that it loads the subscriber count? Unfortunately sp.core.browseUri does not work for playlists.

I also attempted the same with libspotify and seemed to get the same problem. Am I doing something wrong? Is anyone able to reliably fetch playlist subscribers?

To Replciate:

```
var playlist = "spotify:user:crjunkin:playlist:3tNieyc7DFck9BEM2k0IDv";
m.Playlist.fromURI(playlist,function(pl){
    playlist =  pl;
    setTimeout("console.log('Waited: '+playlist.data.subscriberCount)",10000);
    playlist.observe(m.EVENT.CHANGE, function() {
        console.log("Changed: "+playlist.data.subscriberCount);
    });
    console.log(playlist);
    console.log(playlist.data.subscriberCount);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribers can take a while to load in both libspotify and the client. Make sure you're listening to the appropriate callbacks.

Comment: I appreciate this, but no matter how long you wait, the subscriberCount never loads, unless you manually browse to the playlist. Run the code that I added above. The subscriberCount starts as 0. As the playlist loads (and fires change events), it's still 0. After 10 seconds, it's still 0. But if you then visit the playlist, it instantly triggers a change event with the correct count.

Comment: (assuming you haven't loaded that particular playlist already)

Comment: This is currently broken. I've fixed it, and we'll release an updated Dev Preview build in a day or two with the fix.

Comment: appears to be fixed. i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I found this info like so, after much object inspection:

```
var plObj = sp.core.getPlaylist(playlistURI); 
console.log(plObj.subscriberCount);
```

Comment: the problem is that this often returns 0 when it shouldn't, unless you have viewed the playlist recently...(try it on a playlist URI you have never opened)